# Why does the Linux Kernel copy implementation use the AC flag?

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, systems-programming

The implementation of [`copy_user_enhanced_fast_string`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3/source/arch/x86/lib/copy_user_64.S#L200) in the Linux Kernel copy routine uses `stac`/`clac` in the epilog and prolog. `perf annotate` shows the following code:

```
stac 
cmp  $0x40,%edx
jb   0xffffffff91281f5c
mov  %edx,%ecx
rep  movsb %ds:(%rsi),%es:(%rdi)
xor  %eax,%eax
clac
retq
```

`AC` is "Alignment check (or access control) flag".

**What is the reason `stac`/`clac` are used in the routine? What would be the consequences if we simply remove them?**

Comment: Interesting.  I always thought the AC flag had no effect to code runninig in ring 0 anyway.

Comment: @fuz it has a new interpretation under SMAP

Comment: @harold Cool!  I didn't know about that before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally all page access checks are disabled in supervisor-mode and the kernel can read or write to any page regardless of whether its read-only or marked as a supervisor or user page.  However if [Supervisor-Mode Access Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervisor_Mode_Access_Prevention) is enabled (CR4.SMAP = 1), then the AC flag controls whether the kernel can read or write user-mode pages.  If EFLAGS.AC is 0 then reading or writing to user-mode pages will cause a page-fault exception.  If EFLAGS.AC is 1 then kernel is permitted to read and write user mode pages.

The STAC and CLAC instructions were invented to allow quick and easy changing of the AC flag in code like in your example. By setting EFLAGS.AC the REP MOVSB instruction is allowed to access user-mode pages. By clearing EFLAGS.AC at the end, the kernel is once again protected against accidental user-mode accesses that could be exploited by malicious code.

Comment: If not doing `stac` will it ends up in kernel panic?

Comment: @SomeName It probably won't cause a kernel panic, at least not directly. The code is designed to catch page fault exceptions. The `_ASM_EXTABLE_UA(1b, 12b)` line in the kernel source code creates an exception table entry for the REP MOVSB instruction (at label `1:`) that causes the code at label `12:` to be executed if that instruction causes a page fault. If AC is clear then executing REP MOVSB should fault on the first memory access and the `copy_user_enhanced_fast_string` function would return 0, indicating that 0 bytes had been copied. This may end up causing the kernel to panic.